# iTextSharp PDF printing

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

I'm trying to create a method that will send a PDF file directly to my printer (causing the print dialog to appear).

Below is the code I've been working on - most of it found in the forums [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270674/print-pdf-from-asp-net-without-preview). It works fine if I use iTextSharp to create a new PDF document, but as soon as I try to inject some JavaScript into an existing file, I get an exception when calling the `print()` method saying

> Object doesn't support property or method 'print'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        try {
            var x = document.getElementById("frame1");
            x.print();
        }
        catch (err) {
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="load();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <iframe id="frame1" src="C:/1686850_1.pdf"  runat="server" frameborder="0" style="height: 0px; width: 0px;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.CS file

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public partial class Print : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetPDF(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\1686850.pdf"), "C:\\1686850_1.pdf"); //test files
    }

    private void SetPDF(byte[] file, string outputPath)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
        int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
        Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

        Document pdf = new Document(pageSize);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));
        pdf.Open();

        //This action leads directly to printer dialogue
        PdfAction jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
        writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);
        //Omitting this loop and simply adding some text to the file produces the behavior I want.
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
        {
            pdf.NewPage();
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
            writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        }
        pdf.Close();

        //Open the pdf in the frame
        frame1.Attributes["src"] = outputPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way to do this here: http://wskidmore.com/2011/03/pdf-initial-view-settings-itextsharp/

Based on that, I wrote this code:

```
private void PrintMenu()
{
    ...
    var notUriPath = Server.MapPath("~/" + filePathName);

    var doc = new Document();
    var reader = new PdfReader(notUriPath);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
        doc.Open();

        // this action leads directly to printer dialogue
        var jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
        writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);

        var cb = writer.DirectContent;
        doc.AddDocListener(writer);

        for (var p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)
        {
            doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSize(p));
            doc.NewPage();
            var page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, p);
            var rot = reader.GetPageRotation(p);
            if (rot == 90 || rot == 270)
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(p).Height);
            else
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0);
        }

        reader.Close();
        doc.Close();
        File.WriteAllBytes(notUriPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
    }

    theIframeForPrint.Attributes.Add("src", fullFilePath);
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks man, it works.. i copied this code `// this action leads directly to printer dialogue
        var jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
        writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);`

Answer (score 0):

You want to add Javascript to the PDF to open the print dialog, not the web page (unless you really do want the web page print dialog, not the PDF print dialog).  I have done this before, but not with iTextSharp; but a quick Google search should tell you how to add Javascript using iTextSharp to open the print dialog.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing? :) my goal, really, is to print the PDF document from my webpage without using a PDF reader