# Printing a PDF File silently from .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to print a PDF from file silently. I have tried numerous suggestions from other posts on the web, but none have seemed to work. What is the best way of doing this?

If printing from a file is the problem, I could print straight from a `MemoryStream`. I initially convert to PDF from HTML using a library. This renders the PDF exactly how I want it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by silently?

Comment: If by "silently" you mean without the print dialog appearing, I don't think it's possible (but I admit I may be wrong).

Comment: What third party library are you using to print the PDF?

Comment: Does your ASP.NET tag mean you are trying to trying to print a remote file from a web browser? Most browsers' security model will not allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Foxit to do this in the past.  Check out my question/solution here: [Printing a PDF Silently with Adobe Acrobat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868982/c-printing-a-pdf-silently-with-adobe-acrobat)

Comment: This is what i ended up using. It completes the printout completely silenty which is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have a client browser automatically send a pdf from a link to their local printer then you are out of luck.  There's not a browser on the planet that would let you do this.

If you are trying to send a file to a printer that is local to the server, through it's own printer drivers, then see Cole W's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270674/print-pdf-from-asp-net-without-preview).

```
Document pdf = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, 
new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "~1.pdf", FileMode.Create));
pdf.Open();

//This action leads directly to printer dialogue
PdfAction jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);

pdf.Add(new Paragraph("My first PDF on line"));
pdf.Close();

//Open the pdf in the frame
frame1.Attributes["src"] = "~1.pdf";
```

The `PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);` could be changed sending the `false` parameter like this `PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(false);\r", writer);`

I haven't tried it but could be an approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may [try Aspose.Pdf.kit to print the PDF file](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/printing-pdf-files-using-printer-settings-and-page-settings.html) to either physical or virtual printer while hiding the print dialog. In order to hide the print dialog, you only need to [set PrintPageDialog property to false](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/printing-to-an-xps-file-and-hiding-print-dialog.html).

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.